# HTML5 Device Mockups Issue

Tags: css, html, z-index

I'm trying to embed some contents into a HTML5 device mockup. The library that I use for mockup is https://github.com/pixelsign/html5-device-mockups.
I created a button inside 'screen' div but I can not reach to it.

If you inspect [this](https://pixelsign.github.io/html5-device-mockups/) page's elements, you can see that 'screen' div is not reachable with mouse click. I've tried to changed z-index property but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *.screen* div has its property `pointer-events` set to `none` in [general.scss](https://github.com/pixelsign/html5-device-mockups/blob/master/src/scss/general.scss)

Removing the property and rebuilding the CSS should work.

**Note:** I do not know why this property was set to `none` in the first place. Removing it might have some side effects.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution at the same time with you!